# Why find function is not working in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wanted to extract Product name from a chunk. I am using BeautifulSoup, the problem is when i try to fetch product name from `select()` it returns the expected data where when i am trying `find()` it returns none. Why `find()` is not working here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = '''<span id="productTitle" class="a-size-large"> Alien 3 </span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.select('.a-size-large')[0].text.strip())
>>> 'Alien 3'

print(soup.find('.a-size-large')) # Not working ??
>>> None
```

Comment: Per [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), the first argument to `find` is strictly the *name* of the element; try `soup.find('span')`. Or just **keep using `select`**, if you want to use arbitrary [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Comment: You're using CSS selector inside the `find()` function, which doesn't use selectors. The `select()` method uses selectors; that's why one is giving the output and the other isn't

Comment: How can i use class as well, i want to use tag with class, how can i write this i tried `soup.find('span', '.productTitle')` not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) function expects a CSS selector as a parameter. Whereas, the [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) function expects tag names and/or attributes as the parameters.

The docs say (regarding `find()`):

> Signature: find(name, attrs, recursive, string, **kwargs)

So, there are three ways you can get the tag you want:

1. `soup.select('.a-size-large')[0].text.strip()` or
    `soup.select_one('.a-size-large').text.strip()`
2. `soup.find('span', class_='a-size-large').text.strip()` or
   `soup.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-large'}).text.strip()`
3. `soup.find(class_='a-size-large').text.strip()` or
   `soup.find(True, {'class': 'a-size-large'}).text.strip()`

All give `Alien 3` as the output.

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked :) i was looking for 3 solution `soup.find(class_='a-size-large')` but when i tried this with id instead of lass it is not working `soup.find(id_='productTitle')`

Comment: Remove the `_`. It's only for the `class` parameter. Since it is a keyword.

Comment: @TarunK, check the edit. The second option in the 3rd solution will be a better solution for you. The first option doesn't work for attrs like `data-react-id` or similar attrs with `-` in between; but the second option will work for all.

Comment: Sure i will try all cases

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> soup.find('', {'class': 'a-size-large'})
<span class="a-size-large" id="productTitle"> Alien 3 </span>
```

Because you need to specify which attribute you need to search. For first argument it is empty but you can specify any html element like:

```
>>> soup.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-large'})
<span class="a-size-large" id="productTitle"> Alien 3 </span>
```

And then it will search for specific span tags only. But leaving empty will search for all tags with class name equal to given one.

Also avoid using `.` with class name while searching for it.

Comment: Thanks, much helpful :) Conclusion is we cannot use css selector (without tag) in find function, am i right ?

Comment: @TarunK, Actually, you **can't** use CSS selector in find function.

Comment: @TarunK Keyur Potdar Answer has nice explanation, go through that and you will understand it. Mainly the first line will clear your doubt.

Comment: @Shashank, just curious; is `find('')` the same as `find(True)`? The output is the same for both.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar I really spent serious amount of time reading source code and I came to conclusion that they are not same. When we are searching for text and matching it then there are 2 cases. If the given match_against is True then it will return the markup else it will do strict comparisons. Actually it's quite deep and even I am having hard time understanding the code. Have a look at bs4/element.py line number 1731 method. Let me know if you find anything interesting

Comment: @Shashank, Whoa! I was not expecting it to be so deep. Thank you for spending lots of time and pointing me to the relevant source code. I went through it and didn't get exactly what's happening with the `name` but I'll stick to using `True` as I understood that part. I learnt so many new things going through the source code thanks to you.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Same here I also learned so many things. I'll update you with this answer soon when I will get time. Going in Todo list :)